# help in inner join query (get post categories)

Tags: php, database

i have built small forum script

in my index page i am using

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads");
while($threads = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo 'Thread title ' . $threads['thread_title'];
    echo '<br />Thread content ' . $threads['thread'];
}
```

to print the full site posts!

Now i want display the post category and post tags under the title

How i can get the categories and tags of post ?

i have table contain this information

table name -> relations

columns

post_id|category_name

i want join this table and get the category_name of each post!

so what is the right query?

NOTE: my site database is big .. so i want the speedy query

thank you very much

Comment: Is that a one-to-many (one post to many categories) relationship?

Comment: i don't understand , but yes i am using multiple categories like wordpress but this is not wordpress

Comment: Could you please list all columns contained in `threads` and `relations` tables?

Comment: threads -> thread_id,thread_title,thread_content,status -----------<br />relations -> relation_id,cate_id,category_name,thread_id----> cate_id is the category id and thread_id is the post id and category name is the name of the category

Comment: Why do you have `category_name` *and* `cate_id` in the `relations` table? Sounds like you're de-normalising your database

Comment: it's for testing .. but in future i will improve my project an then left join categories table and get category name by cate_id <- this is my idea -- if you have better one that's will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the list of tables and fields they contain for the data that you want to see.

But the general idea should be something like this (assuming threads table has a foreign key on post_id to relations table's post_id):

```
SELECT t.*, r.category_name FROM threads as t
INNER JOIN relations as r on t.thread_id = r.thread_id
```

Just updated the above query based on the fields you just listed.

FYI: if you are concerned about performance, you should do the join of the data in your database query as shown above, executing additional queries for each row in your initial dataset will generate additional calls * number of threads. Now multiple that by the number of users viewing that page and the load on the database grows exponentially, and unnecessarily. All that can be done in one database query so that each user will only trigger one query in the database as opposed to hundreds or thousands potentially per view of the page.

Ok, in that case try something like this:

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(r.category_name ORDER BY r.category_name SEPARATOR " ") as category_name 
FROM threads as t
INNER JOIN relations as r on t.thread_id = r.thread_id
GROUP BY r.thread_id;
```

Comment: it's working and i was trying this query! but there is big problem! ... now i have 3 posts and 100 tag the (mysql_fetch_array) is displaying 103 results! the count of (posts results+relations results)

Comment: first post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. second post title .. ( 103 results!)

Comment: By "tag" you are referring to a category_name in the relations table? so in other words for each thread record you have potentially many relations records, is that correct?

Comment: yes that's right ,tags and categories name in one table named -> relations if that's hard -- how wordpress do this!!!!!!

Comment: @Osama When asking yourself the question "how does Wordpress do this?", the answer is inevitably "in the worst way possible"

Comment: @Dmitry Ah, MySQL. Pissing on standards since 1994. +1 for the nice use of `GROUP_CONCAT` though

Comment: finally! it's working fine now
First post title
howto,ua
second post title
catet,catetest,cates

Comment: but there is small problem .. if posts have no categories .. will not be shown! because there is no matches in post_id.threads and post_id.relations how i can solve this? if i can't i can make a default category!

Comment: @Osama use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN

Comment: I don't know how i can express what's in my heart for you .. but really you fixed my all life problem! thank you very much..